# Implementing WebHook for box.net

Tags: box-api, boxapiv2

I am integrating my website to box.net. Can any body tell how should i write webhook in C# MVC what should be the parameter in application?
What data should be the sample data i get it from box weebhook?

```
public class BoxController : Controller
{
        public async Task<ActionResult> BoxWebhook(??????)
        {

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step would be [setting up the webhook in the Box Admin panel](https://developers.box.com/webhooks/). You can specify what events would trigger the webhook, and also what data to send in the webhook.

Then you would have to configure your server to listen for incoming webhooks from Box and parse them. [This article describes how to receive](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/09/04/introducing-microsoft-asp-net-webhooks-preview/) webhooks in a .NET environment.